# Mapstruct - ignore fields from nested collection - not working when cloning the object

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have the following entity classes and similar DTO classes:

```
class Car {
    Long id;
    List<Owner> ownerList;
}

class Owner {
    Long id;
    String name;
}
```

I used MapStruct with following mappings to :

1. copy to CarDto without IDs

```
    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "ownerList", qualifiedByName = "withoutIdDto")
    CarDto carToCarDto(Car car);

    @Named("withoutIdDto")
    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
    OwnerDto mapOwnerDtoWithoutId(Owner owner);
```

2. clone without IDs

```
    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true) //ignore Car.id
    @Mapping(target = "ownerList", qualifiedByName = "withoutId")
    Car copyCar(Car car);

    @Named("withoutId")
    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true) //ignore Owner.id
    Owner mapOwnerWithoutId(Owner owner);
```

**The problem is:**

The generated mapper for carToCarDto() is calling mapOwnerDtoWithoutId() but copyCar method is not calling mapOwnerWithoutId(). Here's the snippet of generated methods:

```
public Car copyCar(Car car) {
    if (car == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        Car car1 = new Car();
        List<Owner> list = car.getOwnerList();
        if (list != null) {
            car1.setOwnerList(new ArrayList(list)); // no reference to mapOwnerWithoutId
        }

        return car1;
    }
}

public CarDto carToCarDto(Car car) {
    if (car == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        CarDto carDto = new CarDto();
        carDto.setOwnerList(this.ownerListToOwnerDtoList(car.getOwnerList())); //ownerListToOwnerDtoList () calls mapOwnerDtoWithoutId
        return carDto;
    }
}
```

I've following project to reproduce this. Any idea how to fix the test CarMapperTest?

https://github.com/gtiwari333/mapstruct-failing-test-same-object-copy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a difference in the way MapStruct handles 
1. Lists where source and target elements are the same (in line)
2. Lists where source and target are different.

Personally I don't like that difference, but it has been there for a long time. I'm a bit afraid that when we change this (and always do 2.) we might break some implementations.

Having said that I still think MapStruct should prefer an available method over a direct mapping. Please write an issue for that on our GitHub and refer to this one.

Now, a workaround for this is to define an intermediate mapping method like this: List map(List s). MapStruct will generate the implementation for that one and call it as well.

Comment: thanks,   adding List map (List s) worked.  I will create an issue on GitHub.  ```@IterableMapping(qualifiedByName = "withoutId")
    List<Owner> copyOwners(List<Owner> owners);```